# Total states for my variables can have

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> I have 20 variables, each variable can have 2 different states. How
>   many total states exist for all the possible ways the variables can
>   end up?

In other words, if we pick a random state for each of the 20 variables, what is the probability of 1 specific state relative to the entire population?

My initial hunch would be $2^{20}=1048576$ states or $0.000095367%$ probability for 1 particular draw, but I am not sure whether this is a more complex problem involving combinatorics.

Like imagine it as if we have 20 different hats, and each hat has 1 blue and 1 red ball in it. We pick 1 ball from each hat randomly, and the question is how many total ways there are for you to pick 1 ball from each hat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial hunch is right. There are $2^{20}$ possible states. Since $2^{10} = 1024 \approx 1000 = 10^3$ the probability to get any single one of them on a random draw from among $2^{20}$ is just about one in a million. That matches your calculation.

Comment: So I don't have to divide it by anything given that all 20 variables are drawn instead of just 1 of them? I always thought that you have to divide it by something when you draw from more than 1 variable, like the combinations formula suggests?

Comment: The "divide by something" occurs when you are trying to count a subset. You don't need that here. You can check your intuition by writing out all $2^3 = 8$ possible states when there are just $3$ variables.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense, sorry my math skills are a bit rusty, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. No apology required.